# Issue in checking last element of sub array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have data coming in json format like this

```
        {
           feild: ...
           ...
            "transport_details": [
                       {
                       "allotment_id": ObjectId("5b755710d2ccda0978005d6e"),
                       "status": "Active"
                       },
                       {
                         "allotment_id": ObjectId("5b755710d2ccda0978005d6e"), 
                        "status": "Inactive"
                       }
                    ]
        }
```

I have written below java script function like

```
            function checkIfInActive(transportAllotment, id)
        {
            if (transportAllotment.length == 0)
            {
                   return  '<div class="checkbox checkbox-success">' +
                        '<input class="commoncheckbox" type="checkbox" id="studentId_-' + id + '' +
                        '" name="studentId_-' + id + '" value="' + id+ '"' +' >' + '<label></label></div>';
            }
            else
            {
                 var max = transportAllotment.length-1;

                 var status = transportAllotment[max]["status"];

                 if(status != "Active")
                 {
                      return  '<div class="checkbox checkbox-success">' +
                        '<input class="commoncheckbox" type="checkbox" id="studentId_-' + id + '' +
                        '" name="studentId_-' + id + '" value="' + id+ '"' +' >' + '<label></label></div>';
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     return '<div class="checkbox"><input class="disabled-check" type="checkbox" disabled><label></label></div>';
                 }
            }
        }
```

I am trying to return html with class commoncheckbox , if the status of last element of sub array transport_details is Inactive. The above is not returning checkbox with class commoncheckbox in such cases.

Please help!!!

Comment: You've to add `checked` attribute to the checbox you want to enable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var myObj = {
    "aaa":"zzzz",
    "bbb":23,
    "transport_details":[ 
     {
    "status": "Active"
     },
      {
       "status": "Inactive"
      }
    ]
 } 


var status = myObj.transport_details[myObj.transport_details.length - 1].status;

var html = (status === "Active")? '<input type="checkbox">' : '<input type="checkbox" disabled>' ;

$('#banner-message').html(html);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="banner-message">
 
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If status is inactive it will go inside this block. 
Seems the current html literals is messed up a bit. You can use `template literals` which starts with backtck (`) not to confuse with quotes

```
if (status != "Active") {
  return `<div class="checkbox checkbox-success">
          <input class="commoncheckbox" type="checkbox" id="studentId_${id}"
          name="studentId_-${id}"
          value="${id}">
          <label></label>
          </div>`;
}
```

Comment: i am sorry i dont need any checked checkboxes at any condition... i am talking about html returning

Comment: @NidaAmin what does `enabled checkbox` mean